# Solve $x$ for equation : $\sin^2(x) - \cos(x) - 1 = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I am trying to solve $x$ for $\sin^2(x) - \cos(x) - 1 = 0$, for  $0°\leqslant x \lt 360°$.

I have the key with the answer $0°$ but have been unable to confirm this using Wolfram Alpha (I assume I have not done the input correctly) and have also not been able to reach it myself. Which steps should I take to reach that answer?

Comment: The answer is *not* $0^{\circ}$.  An easy way to check this is to plug $x = 0^{\circ}$ into the equation and make sure you get $0$.  So we need $\sin^{2}(0^{\circ}) - \cos(0^{\circ}) - 1 = 0$.  But $\sin(0^{\circ}) = 0$ and $\cos(0^{\circ}) = 1$, so this gives $0 - 1 - 1 = 0$, or $-2 = 0$, which is not true.  $-2$ is never equal to $0$, so $0^{\circ}$ is not a solution.

Comment: @ user46944, from what I can tell, I have presented the problem exactly as in my source with the accompanying key with $0°$ as answer. Here is the source: http://i.imgur.com/pb5L58y.png

Comment: Thank you for explaining.  When they write $0^{\circ} \leq x < 360^{\circ}$, they are not telling you that this is the answer.  They are saying that they want your answer to be between $0^{\circ}$ and $360^{\circ}$.  You actually have to solve for the answer to the problem, and the solutions they want you to find are those between $0^{\circ}$ and $360^{\circ}$.  That is all that the line $0^{\circ} \leq x < 360^{\circ}$ means in the problem.  It is not the key or the solution.  Please consider reading through the answer I posted for a step-by-step solution to the problem.

Comment: @user46944, sorry, it seems I was unclear in my previous comment. What I provided was the source of the problem, not the key and I am under no delusion that it includes the key. The key is another page which for this answer simply says $0°$. Here is the answer in the key: http://i.imgur.com/x6yxMeH.png Here is the problem again but with number: http://i.imgur.com/mAWOo9e.png

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  I still believe the key is incorrect, which happens sometimes.  I solved the problem and got three solutions between $0^{\circ}$ and $360^{\circ}$ (my solution is posted below), but none of them included the solution $0^{\circ}$.  Also, as I mentioned in a post above, there is a really easy way to check that the solution of $0^{\circ}$ is wrong.  Just plug it into the equation, and you will end up with a nonsense statement.  When I plugged $0^{\circ}$ into the equation, I got $-2 = 0$, which is not true.  So $0^{\circ}$ is not a solution.  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use $\displaystyle\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1\iff \sin^2x-1=-\cos^2x$

$$\cos x=0\implies x=(2n+1)90^\circ$$

$$\cos x=-1\implies x=(2m+1)180^\circ$$  where where $m,n$ are integers

I leave for you to find suitable values of $m,n$ so that $x$ lies in the range specified.

Comment: The problem asked for solutions between $0^{\circ}$ and $360^{\circ}$.

Comment: @user46944, Hope that can be managed from the answer

Comment: The reason I mentioned it is that I am considering the point of view of the student.  At the level that these problems are first presented, the student may find this way of expressing the answer confusing.

Comment: @user46944, Added a note

Answer (score 2):

Let $t=\cos x$, then using $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1$, we have $1-t^2 -t -1 = 0 $,
or $t^2+t = t(t+1) = 0$.

Hence the solutions are $\arccos 0, \arccos(-1)$ that lie in the desired range.

Answer (score 1):

So we need to solve $\sin^{2}(x) - \cos(x) - 1 = 0$.  You should recognize that we have a 1 in this equation, and also a $\sin^{2}(x)$.  The trig identity $\sin^{2}(x) + \cos^{2}(x) = 1$ should be jumping out at you.  But we would need to manipulate this identity to involve a $\sin^{2}(x)$ and $1$ on one side of the equal sign.  To do this, subtract $\sin^{2}(x)$ from both sides, and this gives the identity $\cos^{2}(x) = 1 - \sin^{2}(x)$, or, $-\cos^{2}(x) = \sin^{2}(x) - 1$.

So we want to solve $\sin^{2}(x) - \cos(x) - 1 = 0$, and if we get $\cos(x)$ on one side of the equation, we have to solve $\sin^{2}(x) - 1 = \cos(x)$.  But we established above from the $\sin^{2}(x) + \cos^{2}(x) = 1$ identity that $-\cos^{2}(x) = \sin^{2}(x) - 1$, and plugging this into our problem gives that we need to solve:

$$-\cos^{2}(x) = \cos(x)$$

or

$$\cos(x) + \cos^{2}(x) = 0$$

and factoring out a common factor of $\cos(x)$ gives

$$ \cos(x)(1 + \cos(x)) = 0.$$

But $\cos(x)(1 + \cos(x)) = 0$ if either $\cos(x) = 0$ or $1 + \cos(x) = 0$.

So we need to solve two equations.  The first is $\cos(x) = 0$.  Which angles between $0^{\circ}$ and $360^{\circ}$ give cosine of that angle is 0?  Hopefully you said $90^{\circ}$ and $270^{\circ}$.

We also need to solve $1 + \cos(x) = 0$, or $\cos(x) = -1$.  Which angles between $0^{\circ}$ and $360^{\circ}$ give cosine of that angle is -1?  Hopefully you said $180^{\circ}$.

So your three answers to the equation are $x = 90^{\circ}, 180^{\circ},$ and $270^{\circ}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Another approach :**
\begin{align}
\sin^2x-\cos x-\color{red}{1}&=0\\
\sin^2x-\cos x-(\color{red}{\sin^2x+\cos^2x})&=0\\
\cos^2x+\cos x&=0\\
(\cos x+1)\cos x&=0
\end{align}
then $\cos x=0\;\color{blue}{\Rightarrow}\;x=(2n+1)\cdot90^\circ$ and $\cos x=-1\;\color{blue}{\Rightarrow}\;x=(2n+1)\cdot180^\circ$, for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 0):

considering that $1-sin^2 x =cos^2 x$ you can simplify this to an equation contains only $cos x$